# O que significa isso?

Tags: javascript

Qual o significado desse "[0]" nesse JS?

```html
const main = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Olá

Você está usando o método getElementsByTagName que busca por todos elementos cuja tag corresponda com o informado no parâmetro. Esse método deve retornar um array de elementos.

Mais detalhes deste método: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp

Ao retornar um array você precisa acessar cada elemento do através do índice dele (que se assemelha ao endereço doméstico do elemento naquela lista). Isso é feito usando colchetes e entre eles o índice da posição do elemento desejado.

OBS: lembrando que os índices em arrays começam a partir do 0.

No seu caso específico ele está armazenando na variável o primeiro elemento com tag main do documento.

Resumindo: o [0] significa o primeiro elemento da lista.

Valeu .